# Tensorflow, TRT models installation problem

Tags: tensorflow, tensorrt, nvidia-jetson-nano

I installed `tf_trt_models` on  Jetson-nano following the instructions [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/tf_trt_models). I am getting the following error

```
Installed /home/tarik-dev/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slim-0.1-py3.6.egg
Processing dependencies for slim==0.1
Finished processing dependencies for slim==0.1
~/tf_trt_models
Installing tf_trt_models
/home/tarik-dev/tf_trt_models
running install
Checking .pth file support in /home/tarik-dev/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
/home/tarik-dev/.virtualenvs/nanocv/bin/python -E -c pass
TEST FAILED: /home/tarik-dev/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ does NOT support .pth files
bad install directory or PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: I am not sure I am in the right path but here is my suspicion based on this  `https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/ch-python.html` & I read **Public Python 3 modules must be installed in the system Python 3 modules directory, /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. In the install script, because I am in virtualenv, I will need to remove `--user` 
Here is the install.sh script

```
#!/bin/bash

INSTALL_PROTOC=$PWD/scripts/install_protoc.sh
MODELS_DIR=$PWD/third_party/models

PYTHON=python

if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
  PYTHON=$1
fi

echo $PYTHON

# install protoc
echo "Downloading protoc"
source $INSTALL_PROTOC
PROTOC=$PWD/data/protoc/bin/protoc

# install tensorflow models
git submodule update --init

pushd $MODELS_DIR/research
echo $PWD
echo "Installing object detection library"
echo $PROTOC
$PROTOC object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
$PYTHON setup.py install --user
popd

pushd $MODELS_DIR/research/slim
echo $PWD
echo "Installing slim library"
$PYTHON setup.py install --user
popd

echo "Installing tf_trt_models"
echo $PWD
$PYTHON setup.py install --user
```

Comment: Accept your answer to mark your question as solved.

Comment: In sed command form: `sed -i 's/$PYTHON setup.py install --user/$PYTHON setup.py install/g' install.sh`